# Covering spaces!

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, covering-spaces

If one wanted to find all connected covering spaces of a product of two spaces, say $S^1\times  RP(3)$, how would you go about it?

I'm thinking finding the fundamental group of $S^1\times RP(3)$, and then we know that to each  subgroup of $\pi_1(S^1\times RP(3)$(there is s 1-1 correspondence between coverings of a space $X$ and conjugacy classes of subgroups of $\pi_1(X)$) corresponds a covering space of $S^1\times RP(3)$. Is this correct?

If yes, then how would I go about identifying the corresponding covering spaces? Would I simply try to identify which spaces have these subgroups as their fundamental groups?
If I found all these subgroups, would this imply that there cannot be any more connected covering spaces because of this one-to-one correspondence?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a caution, since it's happened before around this time, that it's finals season for grad students (not that I'm assuming anything about abby, I'm just saying...)

Comment: I'm not a graduate student, and it's not the finals season either...but I understand your concern. I'm not looking for an answer, just to see whether I'm on the right track.

Comment: Okay- well, start by finding the universal cover, then use the correspondence between quotients of that by nice group actions and covers of the original space.

Comment: (That is the explicit form of the correspondence you mention between conjugacy classes of subgroups of the fundamental group and covers.)